# How create Swagger JSON for multiple resources

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I am using TEST Application class which consumes three different resource classes

```
 example:-HondaApplication.java
            -carResource.java
            - bikeResource.java
            - planResouce.java
```

I am getting  one JSON file by using OpenAPI-Specification swagger generator. 
so I am looking for three different JSON file.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What type of project is it?

Comment: rest application

Comment: Is it a `Spring` application? If it is, are you using `Springfox` for `Swagger`?

Comment: iam implementing my application in INF-2